Computing $ \binom{n-k}{i} i = (n-k) \binom{n-k-1}{i-1}$
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i}$
This sum was simplified in a paper I was reading with the identitiy: $ \binom{n-k}{i} i = (n-k) \binom{n-k-1}{i-1}$ and I simply cannot find this identity or prove it. I failed by just applying the binomial coefficient definition.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is an application of the absorption identity:
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
Now we have
$$
\binom{n-k}{i} i
= \frac{n-k}{i}\binom{n-k-1}{i-1} i
= (n-k) \binom{n-k-1}{i-1}
$$
